# blade file is not displaying

Tags: php, laravel

when i call a function inside another function in same controller my blade file is not showing

controller 1st function:

```
public function cart_add($id,$prdt_id)
{

    $model = new Cart();
    $model->user_id = $id;
    $model->prdt_id = $prdt_id;
    $model->created_by = 1;
    $model->updated_by = 1;
    $model->created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $model->updated_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $model->save();

    $this->cart_show();

   
}
```

2nd function:

```
 public function cart_show()
{
    $id=1;
    $cart= Cart::select()->where('user_id',$id)->get();     
    $product = Products::get();
    $images= ProductImage::get();
    return view("frontend.maincart", [
        'cart' => $cart,
        'image' => $images,
        'product'=>$product
    ]);
}
```

Comment: did it fix your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

in your first function, return the result of the second function

```php
public function cart_add($id,$prdt_id)
{

    $model = new Cart();
    $model->user_id = $id;
    $model->prdt_id = $prdt_id;
    $model->created_by = 1;
    $model->updated_by = 1;
    $model->created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $model->updated_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $model->save();

    return $this->cart_show();
}
```